# How to convert a more than 1 doc file in a folder into text file using java

Tags: java

I have a code for 1 doc file only .I need to convert multiple doc file in  folder into respective textfile.

Code for Single doc file Into text file:

```
import java.io.*; 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor; 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument; 

public class ReadDocFile { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        File file = null; 

        try { 
            // Read the Doc/DOCx file 
            file = new File("document"); 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis); 
            XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc); 
            String text = ex.getText(); 

            //write the text in txt file 
            File fil = new File("D:\\wordtotextoutput\\java1new.txt"); 
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fil)); 
            output.write(text); 
            output.close(); 
        } catch (Exception exep) { 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: hi avempace can u give code for this full scenario it will helpme lot iam java beginner so only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just give you the logic. you should be able to convert it to java

1. First the input docs files should land into a particular folder.
2. Scan the folder and get the No. of files in the folder.
3. Put a for loop and fetch the file one by one. Put all your code logic here inside the loop.
4. check the file type of the fetched file. if its .doc/.docx process it.
5. Process all the files in the similar way.
6. Later delete the processed file.

Answer (score 0):

From Package `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`
 You can use

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

and then delete the old file if you want to.